# cross domain ajax works in all but android

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, cross-domain, jsonp

I have literally lost hair over the last 2 and a half days i've spent on this problem...

Using phonegap to build an app for iPhone and Android. Cross domain ajax works in my browser and also on iPhone. it will NOT work on Android.

I have not been using jQueryMobile, just jQuery, until i read somewhere that i should be using the mobile version to get cross domain to work on android. So i've changed up the project to suit jMobile. Do i really need to use JqueryMobile in order to get cross domain ajax working?? i would much rather not use it if possible.

tried changing things like $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages=true; $.support.cors = true; to no avail. I'm at a loss. Please help me out

Heres my ajax code

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'URL',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    success: function(response){
        console.log("inside ajax");
        $.each(response, function(i,item){
            var category = "<div class='icon-text'><a class='ajaxify' href='pages/onlineRecipe.html' onclick='$(setOnlineID("+item.id+"))' >"
                +"<p><img alt='Image-alt' width='64' class='wrap-around' id='img"+item.id+"' />"
                +"<strong>"+item.title+"</strong>"
                +"<br/>"+item.desc+"</p></a></div>";

            $('#categories').append(category);
            var img = "#img" + item.id;
            $(img).attr('src', "data:image/png;base64,"+item.image);
            //other bindings
            App.ajaxLinkify($("a.ajaxify"));
            App.addTouchEvents($(".page"));
        });
    },
    error: function(xhs, status, error){
        //output.text('Ha producido un error cargando el dato. Por favor, intèntalo de nuevo.');
        console.log("Ajax not working");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to add this to corresponding php file: header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to check `<access origin="http://www.example.com" />` in **res/xml/config.xml** (cordova 2.3)

Comment: access origin is set to allow load local pages <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
should i edit this? to what?

Comment: i uncommented all of the access origin tags, didnt help. thanks anyway.

Comment: This should be set to domains, that you are requesting from or to * should allow any domain request

Comment: try to comment all access tag except '' <access origin=".*"/> '' It should allow all domains requests.

Comment: i'm afraid that did not work, Lixas. thank you. Actually for some reason it wont even load the local files when i have origin=".*"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this `jQuery.support.cors = true;`

oh and one other tip, just incase it's caching a previous bad call add this to your ajax

```
cache: false,
```

Comment: added cache: false, i already had $.support.cors = true but tried $.jquery.support.cors = true. it produced error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'support' of undefined

Comment: try with out the $, just as i wrote it

Comment: sorry, i assumed what you wrote. still however, jQuery.support.cors = true didnt do anything different.

Comment: whathappens if you just have dataType: 'json',

Comment: jsonp is needed there as php file returns a wrapped json object (or so i believe this to be why). tried it but it doesnt return anything

Comment: im thinking maybe the server (at 000webhost.com) does not support cors, this is why it will not run as type:post, datatype:json, with support.cors = true... from what i gather jsonp isnt supported by androids browser?

Comment: i needed to add CORS support to the server by adding this header to my php file: header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); that was it. thanks

Comment: @user1359079 so you should probably create a new answer yourself and accept that as solution. Current state is missleading.